# using sed, insert a word to the front of a specific line

Tags: bash, sed

I've tried to use this;

```
sed -e 's/    /Close,/g' /home/user/Desktop/original.txt > /home/user/Desktop/updated.txt
```

and the file reads like this:

```
SYMBOL
      16.00 Low,15.85 
      16.91
```

What I am trying to achieve is to insert a word on line 2 in front of 16.00.

I've been frying my brain trying to get it to insert, none of my attempts have been pretty flat, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using the `g` modifier if you only want to do one replacement on the line?

Comment: Does the line you want to insert on begin with spaces or a TAB character?

Comment: can you format your example file so that it displays properly? I'm assuming that there is supposed to be more than one line.

Comment: @Crazysheep Someone has already edited it, we're waiting for enough people to approve the edit.

Comment: consider adding your expected output from your 3 lines of data. Also clarify space or tab question from comment above as part of your question text. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what "specific line" you are trying to match. If it's that exact line:

```
sed -r 's/^\s*16.00/Close,16.00/' /home/user/Desktop/original.txt > /home/user/Desktop/updated.txt
```

If it's something a bit more general, maybe:

```
sed -r 's/^\s*(\d\d\.\d\d\s+Low)/Close,\1/' /home/user/Desktop/original.txt > /home/user/Desktop/updated.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/^[[:space:]]\{1,\}16/Close,16/' /home/user/Desktop/original.txt > /home/user/Desktop/updated.txt
```

`g` is changing several occurance on current working content but by default, sed treat 1 line at a time. In this case, `g` is useless becausse there is only one change maximum per line. Also, the `^` is the begin of each line and not only the first of all lines.